# Search for the most similar string in python

Tags: python, search, chatbot

I'm doing a kind of a chatbot in python for a school project, it's a simple one: I ask a question and it searches a txt file with all the questions and answers that it has and then it gives and answer.
What I want to do is to know how it can search for the most similar question in the database.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ (Joke: You watch Rick & Morty, your IQ should be high enough to solve this problem)

Comment: Add some code, show us you worked, and then we will help/guide you through your problem.

Comment: @byxor all you had to do was give me a name of an algorithm no need to be rude first time ive used stackoverflow and it seems toxic af I'll keep using reddit

Comment: @IMCoins thanks I already made it I was just trying to find some good algorithms for the search

Comment: @Obsession Sorry you saw it that way. I gave you a link pointing to why people downvoted your question (and how to improve it) and then tried to lighten the mood with some humour you'd understand. In future I'll avoid Rick & Morty jokes.

Comment: @byxor I understand, it was just my first post on stackoverflow and didnt know the correct way to ask for information but most people seemed to just downvote or joke instead of actualy helping or explaning what I did wrong anyway doesnt matter, now I know how to do it next time and I finished the AI project for university.

Answer (score 1):

Well I forgot I had posted this but I made the code and its working if anyone wants to use it, I used SequenceMatcher and Levenshtein algorithms.

```
def startChatBot():
cls()
ExitFlag = 0
while (ExitFlag != 1):
    print('Write Exit to return to menu!!')
    FoundFlag = 0        
    Q = input("What is your question? \n")
    if (Q=='Exit'):
        ExitFlag=1
        main()
    elif (Q== 'Que horas são?'):
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
    else:
        bestRatio = 0
        BestDist = 40000
        #SequenceMatcher
        for item in database:
            if SequenceMatcher(None, item, Q).ratio()>AcceptanceRatio and SequenceMatcher(None, item, Q).ratio()>bestRatio:
                    squenceactual = SequenceMatcher(None, item, Q).ratio()
                    bestRatio = squenceactual
                    print('SquenceMatcher Found a better answer in the database with ratio of', bestRatio)
                    S = database.index(item)           
                    print(database[S+1])
                    FoundFlag = 1
        #Levenshtein            
        for item in database:
            actualDistance  = distance(Q, item)
            if (actualDistance < BestDist):
                BestDist = actualDistance
                Solution = database.index(item)
                print('Levenshtein found a better answer in the database with distance of', BestDist)
                FoundFlag = 1
        print(database[Solution+1])


        if FoundFlag == 0:
            print('Answer not found!\n')
            print('Can you add an answer?\n')
            k = input('Y for yes N for no\n')
            if k== 'Y' or k=='y':
                 correct = input('what is the correct answer? \n')
                 with open("BasedeDados.txt", "a") as file:
                      file.write('#')
                      file.write(Q)
                      file.write('#')
                      file.write(correct)
                 #close and reopen database                 
                 openFile()

        elif FoundFlag == 1:
            h = input('Was this the correct answer? Y-Yes N-No \n')
            if h == 'n' or h =='N':
               correct = input('what is the correct answer? \n')
               with open("BasedeDados.txt", "a") as file:
                     file.write('#')
                     file.write(Q)
                     file.write('#')
                     file.write(correct)
               #reopen datababse
               openFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing you can try is use some string similarity package like `fuzzywuzzy`. It uses `difflib` which is a standard library of Python.

Below is a sample code for your use case:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

query = 'user query'
options = [list of all questions in your file]
result = process.extractOne(query, options)
# result will contain best matching option and it's confidence score
```

Again, there are so many better ways to do this, but I think this is simplest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I forgot about this post I ended up using squence matcher and Levenshtein